# Custom UITableViewCell Created Twice ... Driving me mad

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell which I want to dynamically expand and contract when a button is press on the cell. The method is called when the button is pressed but it would appear that the cell is getting created twice.... Therefore resetting the state... I have been pouring over this for days trying different things but am at a loss as to what is wrong...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CategoryCell";

// Create a new Cell if necessary

CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CategoryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 67.0);

    NSLog( @"Cell Creation - Row %d", indexPath.row );

    [cell.expandContractButton addTarget:self action:@selector(expandContractButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else {
    NSLog( @"Cell Found - Row %d", indexPath.row );
}

// Setup the cell ...
```

Log....

```
2012-03-24 11:44:02.158 Review Writer[13523:fb03] Number of rows 1
2012-03-24 11:44:02.172 Review Writer[13523:fb03] Cell Creation - Row 0
2012-03-24 11:44:02.192 Review Writer[13523:fb03] Row 0 - setting height
2012-03-24 11:44:02.197 Review Writer[13523:fb03] Cell Creation - Row 0
```

Any pointers as to why this would be the case ?

Code to populate the cell data

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(CategoryCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"Setting up cell on Row %d - Expanded - %@", indexPath.row, cell.expanded ? @"YES" : @"NO");

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

Category *cat = [categoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.categoryLabel.text = cat.category;
cell.ratingLabel.text = cat.overall_rating;

if (cell.expanded == YES)
{
    [cell expandCell];
}
else {
    [cell collapseCell];
}

cell.reviewText.text = cat.review_text;

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Not Rated"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"0_stars.png"]];
}

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Unsatisfactory"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"1_stars.png"]];
}

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Needs improvement"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"2_stars.png"]];
}

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Meets job requirements"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"3_stars.png"]];
}

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Exceeds job requirements"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"4_stars.png"]];
}

if([cat.overall_rating isEqualToString:@"Outstanding"]){
    [cell.ratingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"5_stars.png"]];
}    

// Put the accessory disclosure button on the cell

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

Code to set the height of the cell...

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
// Use the method that you would have created above to get the cell.

CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *text = cell.reviewText.text;

// Note the 30 is a fudge factor... :-) Otherwise it does not include the last line...

CGFloat width = [cell.reviewText frame].size.width - 30;

CGFloat height = [text sizeWithFont:cell.reviewText.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;

NSLog( @"Row %d - setting height - Expanded = %@", indexPath.row, cell.expanded ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

if (cell.expanded == NO)
{
    height = 0;
}

return height + 67; 
}
```

Code to expand / collapse the cell ...

```
- (IBAction) expandContractButtonPressed:(id) sender{

CategoryCell *clickedCell = (CategoryCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell*)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:clickedButtonPath];

NSLog( @"EXPAND / COLLAPSE Row %d Exanded = %@", clickedButtonPath.row, clickedCell.expanded ? @"YES" : @"NO");

if (clickedCell.expanded == YES)
{
    NSLog( @"Collapse" );
    [cell collapseCell];
    clickedCell.expanded = NO;
}
else {
    NSLog( @"Expand" );
    [cell expandCell];
    clickedCell.expanded = YES;
}

NSLog( @"Expanded after = %@", clickedCell.expanded ? @"YES" : @"NO" );

NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:clickedButtonPath, nil];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:NO];
}
```

Comment: Let me take a guess, maybe somehow you send `reloadData`, or some other __reload__ message to UITableView twice?

Comment: Does CategoryCell come with a .xib file? Post this class please, the code you posted wasn't enough to identify this problem.

Comment: The CategoryCell did startup with an XIB then I converted to be programmatically created...

Comment: I do call [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:NO]; when the cell expand / collapse button is pressed... but again this appears to call the cell creation twice

Comment: Guys solved the problem with storing the expanded state in the datastore and thus when the cells are re-created the data and state is stored outside of the cells ... which kinda makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess, since you have provided only small parts of your code: maybe you have more than one section. You only check the row, but not the section, thus the code can be called for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless, your code should still be able to handle this situation (multiple creation) and properly show the cell.

You didn't show us the code for setting the height and content of the cell.

You should be o.k. if you keep only cell creation code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
and move all cell setup code in `willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: Cheers for the pointers... I have moved my code to set the contents of the cell as described above. I have also included other parts of my code in my post above ...

Comment: Could you also post a bit longer log (from your NSLogs)? For. example when you try to expand/collapse cell...